# Many to one mapping Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am doing many to one mapping in hibernate. I am using the existing tables which I created earlier for one to many mapping (customer and order) but when I am trying to map and update those table I couldn't able to I don't know how should I processed? and I would like to insert the data meaning I would like to create some more orders using command line runner for that customer.

Could you please help me with this

Appreciate your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as a text.

Answer (score 1):

**Mapping one-to-many and many-to-one association**

> Both associations are the same association seen from the perspective of the owing and subordinate entities and respectively.

```
    Student     one-to-many     Address
    Address     many-to-one     Student
```

@OneToMany annotation can be applied to a field or property value of "one" end entity class for a collection or an array representing the mapped "many" end of the association.

@ManyToONe relationship between two entities is by managing the FK(Foreign key) of the "one" end entity, as a column in the "many" entity table.

````
> **Bidirectional one-to-many using ```@JoinColumn```**

@Entity
public class Student{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CasecadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="Student_FK")
    public set<Address> getAddress(){
       return address;
}
}
````

> One-to-Many side as the owing side, You have to remove the mappedBy element and set the `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn` as insertable and updatable to false. This Solution is not optimized and will produce some additional `UPDATE Statement`.

```
@Entity
public class Address{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CasecadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_FK", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Student student;
}
```

For more details look at this link [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

Comment: Please vote up if this ans is useful for you @Naresh

Comment: I can see fk column in table but I would like to update records in order table
what should I do ?

Comment: I updated my answer, plz take a look again both `Student` and `Address` class.